# How to iterate through string one word at a time in zsh

Tags: while-loop, zsh, expansion

How do I modify the following code so that when run in zsh it expands `$things` and iterates through them one at a time?

```
things="one two"

for one_thing in $things; do
    echo $one_thing
done
```

I want the output to be:

```
one 
two
```

But as written above, it outputs:

```
one two
```

(I'm looking for the behavior that you get when running the above code in bash)

Comment: Does that mean that `zsh` is not word-splitting `$things` when it is the list of a `for` loop?  Is it entering the body of the loop just once?  Answer, after fighting through the configuration script, is "Yes".  Scratch `zsh` from the list of usable shells; that's just too non-POSIX-shell like.  I can't even be bothered to start thinking about how it might be configurable to work 'normally'.

Comment: You might not like it but that behaviour is completely POSIX compliant, and as far as I know is the expected behaviour for the sh shell.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In order to see the behavior compatible with Bourne shell, you'd need to set the option `SH_WORD_SPLIT`:

```
setopt shwordsplit      # this can be unset by saying: unsetopt shwordsplit
things="one two"

for one_thing in $things; do
    echo $one_thing
done
```

would produce:

```
one
two
```

However, it's recommended to use an array for producing word splitting, e.g.,

```
things=(one two)

for one_thing in $things; do
    echo $one_thing
done
```

---

You may also want to refer to:

[3.1: Why does $var where var="foo bar" not do what I expect?](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq03.html)

Comment: Rather than set `shwordsplit` globally, you can enable `sh`-style word splitting (using `IFS`, of course) for a single parameter with `${=things}`.

Comment: @chepner, what would that look like?  I tried `IFS=' '; for one_thing in ${=things}; do` but got a `bad substitution` error

Comment: @RobBednark Why don't you use an array?

Comment: It should just be `for one_thing in ${=things}; do`. What version of `zsh` are you using? Works for me in 4.3.10. The array is a better idea, though, since you don't have to rely on using a string delimiter that isn't present in any of the individual items.

Comment: @chepner, I'm using zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0)

Comment: Someone zsh guru may very well explain to the rest of us why this practice is there at all. I mean, how can it be default to _not_ split into substrings in a loop?

Comment: setopt shwordsplit does not seem to work with zsh 5.3.1., nor {=things}. Only IFS=" " did the trick, and ${(z)things} as stated in the other answer.

Comment: Are arrays POSIX compliant? I thought they weren't.

Answer (score 22):

Another way, which is also portable between Bourne shells (sh, bash, zsh, etc.):

```
things="one two"

for one_thing in $(echo $things); do
    echo $one_thing
done
```

Or, if you don't need `$things` defined as a variable:

```
for one_thing in one two; do
    echo $one_thing
done
```

Using `for x in y z` will instruct the shell to loop through a list of words, `y, z`.

The first example uses [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution) to transform the string `"one two"` into a list of words, `one two` (no quotes).

The second example is the same thing without `echo`.

Here's an example that doesn't work, to understand it better:

```
for one_thing in "one two"; do
    echo $one_thing
done
```

Notice the quotes. This will simply print

```
one two
```

because the quotes mean the list has a single item, `one two`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `z` variable expansion flag to do word splitting on a variable

```
things="one two"

for one_thing in ${(z)things}; do
    echo $one_thing
done
```

Read more about this and other variable flags in `man zshexpn`, under "Parameter Expansion Flags."

Comment: Finally all the above answers didn't work just this one.

Answer (score 3):

You can assume the Internal Field Separator (IFS) on bash to be \x20 (space).  This makes the following work:

```
#IFS=$'\x20'
#things=(one two) #array
things="one two"  #string version

for thing in ${things[@]}
do
   echo $thing
done
```

With this in mind you can implement this in many different ways just manipulating the IFS; even on multi-line strings.